# Alternative to gnupg providing ssh-agent replacement too?

Tags: ssh, pgp

Is there an alternative to gnupg, which also provides something like gpg-agent to replace ssh-agent and use ssh-keys generated from the gpg keys?

(I am frustrated with pinentry, how it doesn't work when sshing into a machine and gpg-agent ignoring GPG_TTY because there had been some updatestartuptty been issued.)